# Can't delete own comment when revisiting Close Vote review page

Tags: bug, comments, review, vote-to-close

When reviewing Close Votes, I sometimes leave a comment. I noticed that after reviewing, when going back to the review item, I can *edit* the comment but not *delete* it; the 'Delete' link which is visible upon hovering over the comment isn't shown. See the demo below; first, the situation on the regular Q&A page and then the behaviour of the review queue:

[image]