# Let moderators delete comments while reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

Moderators can delete comments from Q&A pages by hovering over them; a red link appears, similar to how deleting one's own comments works:

[image]

However, this functionality is not available in the review queues. Can it please be added? It *is* possible to flag a comment as No Longer Needed, but that takes an extra click and more mouse movement.

This is similar to [Can't delete own comment when revisiting Close Vote review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349549/295232) but that only happens when viewing a completed review queue item; this also pertains to active review queue tasks.